# publishing (.asmx) file error Unable to open the Web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

i had created a web services project in ASP.NET and moved it from pc1 to pc2, the issue is i am unable to publish .asmx file in pc2 here is the error

```
  Preparing to publish files...
Connecting to C:\Users\ITA\Desktop\Ws...
Unable to open the Web site 'C:\Users\ITA\Desktop\Ws'.  The Web site 'C:\Users\ITA\Desktop\Ws' does not exist.
Unable to open the Web site 'C:\Users\ITA\Desktop\Ws'.  The Web site 'C:\Users\ITA\Desktop\Ws' does not exist.
```

i had edited the  `<publishUrl>C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Ws</publishUrl>` to the new existing folder but the issue is still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by clicking on the setting tab as below 
[image]

then click on Publish 
[image]

i don't have any explanation why this works, but it works without modifying anything.